# Count number of objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this method in my javascript that calls retrieves the URL response and counts the number of objects in the JSON. It suppose to return me value of 3 but its returning me 63 instead. Is there anything that I am doing wrongly?

This is my json

```
   [
        {
            "crisisID": 1,
            "name": "Test1",
            "positionInCMO": "General",
            "threatLevel": 4,
            "crisisType": "Type1",
            "affectedArea": "Area1",
            "estimatedCasualties": 10000,
            "crisisDuration": "Duration1",
            "crisisDetails": "Detail1",
            "courseOfAction": "Action1",
            "consequencesOfAction": "Consequence1",
            "cleanUpAction": "CleanUp1"
        },
        {
            "crisisID": 2,
            "name": "Test2",
            "positionInCMO": "General",
            "threatLevel": 5,
            "crisisType": "Type2",
            "affectedArea": "Area2",
            "estimatedCasualties": 10000,
            "crisisDuration": "Duration2",
            "crisisDetails": "Detail2",
            "courseOfAction": "Action2",
            "consequencesOfAction": "Consequence2",
            "cleanUpAction": "CleanUp2"
        },
        {
            "crisisID": 3,
            "name": "Test3",
            "positionInCMO": "General",
            "threatLevel": 4,
            "crisisType": "Type3",
            "affectedArea": "Area3",
            "estimatedCasualties": 10000,
            "crisisDuration": "Duration3",
            "crisisDetails": "Detail3",
            "courseOfAction": "Action3",
            "consequencesOfAction": "Consequence3",
            "cleanUpAction": "CleanUp3"
        }
    ]
```

This is my javascript code

```
 function checkForNotifications(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/CMOtoPMO/proposal/", 
        type: "GET",
        success: function(notification) {
            //Check if any notifications are returned - if so then display alert
             alert(Object.keys(notification).length);
        },
        error: function(data){
            //handle any error 
             alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you check notification.length?

Comment: @Dinesh im using Object.keys(notification).length

Comment: Recheck whether url `http://localhost:8080/CMOtoPMO/proposal` is returning same json file or different one.

Comment: Sorry took out the "//more objects comments" but it is suppose to return me the number of objects

Comment: I think you can just use `notification.length` or maybe you need to parse `notification` first. `notification` is an array, not an object. Its items, though they are objects in themselves, are just array items, not (named) properties.

Comment: as suggested by dinesh notification.length is enough for your result

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. i just needed notification.length as suggested.